# Select2 multiselect options to display options in another multiselect

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-select2

I have just switched one of my multiselects to `select2` as my previous checkbox multiselect was incompatible with my new page template CSS and looked very out of place.

What is meant to happen is in the first multiselect (now `select2`), users can select their plethora of options and a second multiselect below would populate with the relevant options that are tied to the first already selected and the field read only. This worked fine previously but is no longer doing so.

This is the code I'm using. The options for `hazards` in the `select2` are pulled from a DB which is working as intended.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#hazards').select2();
});

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let hprops = document.querySelector('#hp_codes')
  document.querySelector('#hazards').addEventListener('change', e => {
    let options = e.target.options;
    let hazards = [];
    for (var i = 0, l = options.length; i < l; i++) {
      if (options[i].selected) {
        hazards.push(options[i].value);
      }
    }

    hprops.innerHTML = '';
    hprops.setAttribute('disabled', true); // disable until we get the data in there
    // ajax to get actual data ...
    let results = []
    if (hazards.includes("H200") || hazards.includes("H201")) results.push('HP1')
    if (hazards.includes('H300') || hazards.includes("H301")) results.push('HP6')
    if (hazards.includes('H400') || hazards.includes("H410")) results.push('HP14')

    results.forEach(r => hprops.innerHTML += `<option selected value='${r}'>${r}</option?`)
    hprops.removeAttribute('disabled');

  })
})

// array_unique compressed:
    function array_unique(d){var c="",b={},e="";var a=function(h,g){var f="";for(f in g){if(g.hasOwnProperty(f)){if((g[f]+"")===(h+"")){return f}}}return false};for(c in d){if(d.hasOwnProperty(c)){e=d[c];if(false===a(e,b)){b[c]=e}}}return b}


var optionValues = [];
$('#hp_codes').each(function() {
  optionValues.push($(this).val());
  $(this).remove(); // remove the option element
});

var cleanedArray = array_unique(optionValues); // clean the array

// let's go to paint the new options
for(var i in cleanedArray) {
  var opt = $('<option/>')
                .attr('value', cleanedArray[i]) // note that the value is equal than the text
                .text(cleanedArray[i]);
  $('#hp_codes').append(opt);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

          <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <label class="control-label modal-label">Hazard Statements: </label>
              <span class="text-danger">*</span> </div>
            <div class="mb-3 col-sm-8">
              <select class="form-control select2" data-toggle="select2" id="hazards" name="hazards" multiple required>           
              <option value="H200">H200</option>
              <option value="H201">H201</option>              
              <option value="H300">H300</option>
              <option value="H301">H301</option>              
              <option value="H400">H400</option>
              <option value="H410">H410</option>              
              </select>             
            </div>
          </div>
          </br>
          <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <label class="control-label modal-label">HP Codes: </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <select class="form-control" name="hp_codes" id="hp_codes" multiple readonly>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
```

When I debug this in the browser, it's currently showing that
`$` on this line `$('#hp_codes').each(function() {` is undefined. I'm unsure how to resolve this as it was working fine previously.

**Edit: This is how it should work without JQuery**

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let hprops = document.querySelector('#hp_codes')
  document.querySelector('#hazards').addEventListener('change', e => {
    let options = e.target.options;
    let hazards = [];
    for (var i = 0, l = options.length; i < l; i++) {
      if (options[i].selected) {
        hazards.push(options[i].value);
      }
    }

    hprops.innerHTML = '';
    hprops.setAttribute('disabled', true); // disable until we get the data in there
    // ajax to get actual data ...
    let results = []
    if (hazards.includes("H200") || hazards.includes("H201")) results.push('HP1')
    if (hazards.includes('H300') || hazards.includes("H301")) results.push('HP6')
    if (hazards.includes('H400') || hazards.includes("H410")) results.push('HP14')

    results.forEach(r => hprops.innerHTML += `<option selected value='${r}'>${r}</option?`)
    hprops.removeAttribute('disabled');

  })
})

// array_unique compressed:
    function array_unique(d){var c="",b={},e="";var a=function(h,g){var f="";for(f in g){if(g.hasOwnProperty(f)){if((g[f]+"")===(h+"")){return f}}}return false};for(c in d){if(d.hasOwnProperty(c)){e=d[c];if(false===a(e,b)){b[c]=e}}}return b}


var optionValues = [];
$('#hp_codes').each(function() {
  optionValues.push($(this).val());
  $(this).remove(); // remove the option element
});

var cleanedArray = array_unique(optionValues); // clean the array

// let's go to paint the new options
for(var i in cleanedArray) {
  var opt = $('<option/>')
                .attr('value', cleanedArray[i]) // note that the value is equal than the text
                .text(cleanedArray[i]);
  $('#hp_codes').append(opt);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

          <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <label class="control-label modal-label">Hazard Statements: </label>
              <span class="text-danger">*</span> </div>
            <div class="mb-3 col-sm-8">
              <select class="form-control" id="hazards" name="hazards" multiple required>           
              <option value="H200">H200</option>
              <option value="H201">H201</option>              
              <option value="H300">H300</option>
              <option value="H301">H301</option>              
              <option value="H400">H400</option>
              <option value="H410">H410</option>              
              </select>             
            </div>
          </div>
          </br>
          <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <label class="control-label modal-label">HP Codes: </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <select class="form-control" name="hp_codes" id="hp_codes" multiple readonly>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Please try to make a runnable stack snippet with an example without the PHP code involved. Use the `<>` icon on the editor toolbar. To the HTML, will need to pick jquery for the HTML section of the snippet from the left side of the snippet editor.

Comment: @PaulT. Cheers - I've editted the OP to include a snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping closer to your original code, I believe this is what is needed?
The `addEventListener` was not firing for some reason for `#hazards`, so I used `$('#hazards').on('change', ...` instead.

Also, it seems as if all the code after the `DOMContentLoaded` handler is not used?
Anyway, I added a alternative unique function to filter an array, commented-out, if you might find it useful.

```js
//    $(document).ready(function() {
//        $('#hazards').select2();
//    });

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    $('#hazards').select2();
  let hprops = document.getElementById('hp_codes')
//      document.querySelector('#hazards').addEventListener('change', e => {
// The hazards addEventListener was not firing?
  $('#hazards').on('change', e => {
    let options = e.target.options;
    let hazards = [];
    for (var i = 0, l = options.length; i < l; i++) {
      if (options[i].selected) {
        hazards.push(options[i].value);
      }
    }

    hprops.innerHTML = '';
    hprops.setAttribute('disabled', true); // disable until we get the data in there
    // ajax to get actual data ...
    let results = []
    if (hazards.includes("H200") || hazards.includes("H201")) results.push('HP1')
    if (hazards.includes('H300') || hazards.includes("H301")) results.push('HP6')
    if (hazards.includes('H400') || hazards.includes("H410")) results.push('HP14')

    results.forEach(r => hprops.innerHTML += `<option selected value="${r}">${r}</option>`)
    hprops.removeAttribute('disabled');
  })
})

// array_unique compressed:
function array_unique(d){var c="",b={},e="";var a=function(h,g){var f="";for(f in g){if(g.hasOwnProperty(f)){if((g[f]+"")===(h+"")){return f}}}return false};for(c in d){if(d.hasOwnProperty(c)){e=d[c];if(false===a(e,b)){b[c]=e}}}return b}
/* // an alternative unique
function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}
*/
var optionValues = [];
//    $('#hp_codes').each(function() { // this removed the select!
$('#hp_codes').children().each(function() {
  optionValues.push($(this).val());
  $(this).remove(); // remove the option element
});

var cleanedArray = array_unique(optionValues); // clean the array
//    var cleanedArray = optionValues.filter(onlyUnique); // clean the array

// let's go to paint the new options
for(var i in cleanedArray) {
  var opt = $('<option/>')
                .prop('value', cleanedArray[i]) // note that the value is equal than the text
                .text(cleanedArray[i]);
  $('#hp_codes').append(opt);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

          <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <label class="control-label modal-label">Hazard Statements: </label>
              <span class="text-danger">*</span> </div>
            <div class="mb-3 col-sm-8">
              <select class="form-control select2" data-toggle="select2" id="hazards" name="hazards" multiple required>           
              <option value="H200">H200</option>
              <option value="H201">H201</option>              
              <option value="H300">H300</option>
              <option value="H301">H301</option>              
              <option value="H400">H400</option>
              <option value="H410">H410</option>              
              </select>             
            </div>
          </div>
          </br>
          <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <label class="control-label modal-label">HP Codes: </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <select class="form-control" name="hp_codes" id="hp_codes" multiple readonly>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Worked perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simplified your code and placed the core logic to trigger the change. This will automatically react to any selection or removal from hazard options.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Expense Tracker</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#hazards').select2();

$('#hazards').on('change', function(){

  console.log($(this).val());

  $('#hp_codes').html('');

     $($(this).val()).each(function(i, node){

         //node is the value selected from Hazards

         //do the db call here.. I have just used 1 value, but this can be array of values resulted from DB

          var opt = $('<option/>')
                .attr('value', node+' - DB options') // note that the value is equal than the text
                .text(node+' - DB options');
          $('#hp_codes').append(opt);

     });

   });
});


</script>
    </head>
    <body>
    

          <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <label class="control-label modal-label">Hazard Statements: </label>
              <span class="text-danger">*</span> </div>
            <div class="mb-3 col-sm-8">
              <select class="form-control select2" data-toggle="select2" id="hazards" name="hazards" multiple required>           
              <option value="H200">H200</option>
              <option value="H201">H201</option>              
              <option value="H300">H300</option>
              <option value="H301">H301</option>              
              <option value="H400">H400</option>
              <option value="H410">H410</option>              
              </select>             
            </div>
          </div>
          </br>
          <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <label class="control-label modal-label">HP Codes: </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <select class="form-control" name="hp_codes" id="hp_codes" multiple readonly>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks for answering. I'm not sure that this will achieve what I'm trying to do (or what it used to do rather). The hazards are stored in a DB whereas the HP Codes aren't - these were taken directly from the original javascript, and the HP Codes mutliselect field would then display separate options not including the hazards. I've edited the OP to include what this should look like without `select2` and JQuery.